# Is it there a way to stop kalarm error messages from appearing?

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I use kalarm to schedule a lot of terminal actions in an automation process that involves an internet connection, and kalarm is indeed doing great work. But there are certain days in which the error windows are also a lot when the internet fails.

I wonder if there is a way to configure kalarm to **not** show these error messages/windows.

I know that I can prevent errors from appearing just after the error shows the windows and I choose not to receive individual error messages. But what I wish is to make kalarm's default behavior to not show error messages anymore.

I am using only LTS official Ubuntu distributions. In this case it is 12.04 LTS. 
KDE and KAlarm are updated.

If you need further information/details please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable errors on pre-alarm scripts in the Special Actions button, where you edit the alarm. Unfortunately, I don't see a good way of doing it for simple terminal scripts.

What you might want to do is just modify the scripts you have running to check whether the Internet is up or not. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929368/how-to-test-a-internet-connection-in-bash) for checking the status of an Internet connection from Bash.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am checking the stackoverflow question that you suggest me but I yet think it can be complicated to make individual scripts for 500 different terminal commands. Anyway I will check it later in order to see how viable it is for this case and if possible I will implement it. I appreciate your answer. Upvote. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need 500 different scripts, just one script to wrap the others with.

Answer (score 1):

Command alarms should have the option to ignore execution errors in the same way that pre-alarm actions have. I've raised an enhancement request for KAlarm - https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=315401.

David Jarvie.
KAlarm author.

Comment: Hello @DavidJarvie. I wonder if is it there any evolution on this enhancement request. Thank you very much.