# Is it there a Text User Interface (terminal application) which does what Kalarm do?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, cron, tui

Since there's no updates on the enhancement request raised by [@DavidJarvie](https://askubuntu.com/users/133278/david-jarvie) on the KAlarm Project, documented in my previous question over here: https://askubuntu.com/a/257843/9598, I started wondering if is it there a scheduler whose features preferably includes (and perhaps "only includes") a text user interface.

I have tried CRON to schedule my tasks but, as they are too many (hundreds of commands a day), in certain cases CRON isn't running some of them. But, if there is a proficient CRON Text User Inteface which offers at least some of the KAlarm features, it will be welcome.

Here's a screenshot of what I find in KAlarm's GUI and which I would like to find in a TUI.

[image]

The reason for this need is that SSH support is needed for this task, which can't be solved efficiently via GUI. What I do right now is to Remote Desktop the Server in order to do the scheduling.

Thanks in advance.

---

@muru has ponted in a comment to the `at` command. Which seems good but it clearly states in the [at's man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/at.1):

> ```
>     3. To have a job reschedule itself, at can be invoked from within  the
>        at-job.  For  example,  this daily processing script named my.daily
>        runs every day (although crontab is a more appropriate vehicle  for
>        such work):
>
>        # my.daily runs every day
>        daily processingat now tomorrow < my.daily
> ```

I have mentioned before that I won't use CRON anymore for this task, so I guess a standalone text mode application will be more suitable for the scheduling case. Thank you very much @muru!

Comment: There's also [`at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/at.1).

Comment: @muru I've added an edit related to your suggestion. I appreciate that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As Velkan said, you can use the command `man alarm`.

Or you can refer to the Kalarm manual online: https://docs.kde.org/trunk5/en/kdepim/kalarm/cmdline-operation.html#cmdline-schedule

Comment: Right. But what I am looking for is to stop using kalarm and use an alternative. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oh.... I see ;-)

Comment: I've modified your title to show that

Comment: Thank you very much. But I don't wish a "command-line tool to Kalarm?". I am looking for a command line tool which does what KAlarm do. I am rewording my question in order to avoid confusion. Thank you!